# GridSearchCV: Hyperparameters for multiple pipeline steps without repetition?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, grid-search, hyperparameters

Is it possible to nest the GridSearch parameters for each step of the pipeline model instead of having to duplicate parameters? In my example I want to search over both the model space and the feature selection space simultaneously, see below code:

```py
pipe = Pipeline(
    steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor),
           ("feature_selection", "passthrough"),
           ("classifier", KNeighborsClassifier())
    ]
)

parameters = [
    {
        "classifier": [LogisticRegression()],
        "classifier__C": [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
        "feature_selection": [GenericUnivariateSelect(mode='k_best')],
        "feature_selection__param": [13,12,11,10,9,8,7],
    },
    {
        "classifier": [LogisticRegression()],
        "classifier__C": [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
        "feature_selection": [PCA()],
        "feature_selection__n_components": [2, 4, 8, 10,12],
    },
    {
        "classifier": [KNeighborsClassifier()],
        "classifier__n_neighbors": [2, 4, 6 ,8, 10,12],
        "feature_selection": [GenericUnivariateSelect(mode='k_best')],
        "feature_selection__param": [13,12,11,10,9,8,7],
    },
    {
        "classifier": [KNeighborsClassifier()],
        "classifier__n_neighbors": [2, 4, 6 ,8, 10,12],
        "feature_selection": [PCA()],
        "feature_selection__n_components": [2, 4, 8, 10,12],
    },
]
```

Wishful thinking if it's possible to do something more compact like this:

```py
parameters = [
    {
        "feature_selection": [GenericUnivariateSelect(mode='k_best'),PCA()],
        "feature_selection__n_components": [2, 4, 8, 10,12],
        "feature_selection__param": [13,12,11,10,9,8,7],
        
        "classifier": [LogisticRegression(),KNeighborsClassifier()],
        
        "classifier__C": [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
        "classifier__n_neighbors": [2, 4, 6 ,8, 10,12], 
        
        # Will get errors as parameters don't match in all cases
    },
]
```

Now this code won't run of course because the parameters will be mismatched, but how would be the best way to do this if I had many more variations? Just copy and pasting code works for a few, but quickly grows the more variations you add.